# Export All Views to Text Files

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssis, parallel-data-warehouse

There are a number of views in a database on one of our servers. I need to save all the view definitions as text files in the following format:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('<[Schema_Name].[VIEW_NAME]>') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW <[Schema_Name].[VIEW_NAME]>
GO

<<View Definition Here>>

GO

GRANT SELECT ON <[Schema_Name].[VIEW_NAME]> TO [PUBLIC]
GO
```

The text file should be named as **Schema_Name.VIEW_NAME.txt**

I don't want to do this manually as this would take up all my time. Any idea if this can be automated? Maybe using SSIS or something?

Comment: **[SMO Scripter](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)** you can do everything like in `Generate Script GUI from SSMS`. Another possibility is reinventing wheel with dynamic SQL and using system objects.

Comment: I am on Parallel Data Warehouse, which doesn't have all features like SSMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all views with this query:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    av.name,
    sm.definition,
    'IF OBJECT_ID('''+s.name+'.'+av.name+''') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW '+s.name+'.'+av.name+'
GO

'+sm.definition+'

GO

GRANT SELECT ON '+s.name+'.'+av.name+' TO [PUBLIC]
GO' AS script
FROM sys.views AS av
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sm
    ON av.object_id = sm.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON av.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

just create cursor with this select, and for each row store data to file with something like this:

```
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @script + ' > C:\' + @schema + '.' + @view_name + '.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

Answer (score 5):

May `information_schema` be your friend:

```
SELECT v.TABLE_SCHEMA AS View_Schema
    ,v.table_name AS View_Name
    ,v.VIEW_DEFINITION AS Create_View_Script
FROM information_schema.VIEWS v
JOIN information_schema.columns c ON v.table_schema = c.table_schema
    AND v.table_name = c.table_name
GROUP BY v.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,v.table_name
    ,v.VIEW_DEFINITION
```

[image]